# Are there any pre-trained NER entity-linking models available?

Tags: nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition, entity-linking

I want to run entity-linking for a project of mine. I used Spacy for the NER on a corpus of documents. Is there an existing linking model I can simply use to link the entities found?

The documentation I have found seems to be how to train a custom one.

Examples:

https://spacy.io/api/kb

https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/4511

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

spaCy does not distribute pre-trained entity linking models. See [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/6665) for some comments on why not.

Answer (score 0):

I found one - Facebook GENRE:
https://github.com/facebookresearch/GENRE

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.